# Why does SubEclipse prompt me to check in items marked as ignored in SVN-ignore?

Tags: eclipse, svn, ignore

I"m using Eclipse Juno on Mac 10.7.5 (Java 6) with SubEclipse.  I'm also using SVN for version control.  Despite the fact that I have set some files/folders to ignore using "svn propedit ignore ." a the command line ….

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:sbadmin davea$ svn propedit ignore .
```

displays

```
target
.classpath
.settings
.project
bin
```

When I'm in Eclipse, right click on my project (sbadmin) and select Team -> Commit, the dialog always shows ".classpath" and ".project" as files to check-in, despite the fact I want them ignored.  Any way I can correct this?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the property name wrong. It's not `ignore` but `svn:ignore`. That is why the files are not ignored and your svn plugin in Eclipse wants to add them, because you set the list of files in the wrong property so it is not taken into account.

Since you seem comfortable on the command line, here are the commands to fix this:

```
svn pget ignore . > ignore.txt       # backup the content of ignore
svn pset svn:ignore . -F ignore.txt  # set svn:ignore from the backup
svn pdel ignore                      # delete the ignore property
```

Or as the other answer points out you could also use your Eclipse plugin to set ignore patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse seems to ignore some of the global SVN settings. If you want those files ignored in *all* your projects, probably the easiest way would be to add them to Eclipse's own list of ignored resources.

Just go to *Preferences -> Team -> Ignored Resources* and add the respective patterns to the list.